# Multiple projects - 1 package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package

I'm working with multiple projects, each one separated from the others in my server. So my problem is that I have a Core project that have all the functions I need, and in Laravel projects it's annoying to copy/paste everything every time. I was thinking to create a package and install it in all my Laravel projects via composer, but it bothers me the fact that every time I want to add a feature or perform a minor bug fix, I will have to do a composer update in every project (I have more than 20 actually).

I just came up with some ideas, let me know what do you think about it and if you will use some different idea:

- Create a Model/Class that includes my main php core library directly from the server (Remember that I have all the projects in the same server). I will just need to call the Model/class and it will import all the functions. I will just need to keep updated the main library code every time I perform a minor bug fix or any new implementation.
- Create a package where inside will have all code I could need to use in all projects (main library). This would be perfect, since I want just use the composer install command get the package installed in my project. I'm not concerned at all with this solution, because I have more than 20 diferent projects and I will need to do more than 20 composer update every time I perform a minor bug fix or new implementation.
- The last one is to do a generic composer where it contains all the packages I would need (almost all the projects use the same composer.json) and create a symlink between all the projects. I will install the packages in one folder and keep that updated everytime I perform some new task, and the symlink will keep the folders updated in every project.

What do you think about that options? I think I will go for the 3rd one, but wanna know your opinions or if you have the same problem and works with other solutions.

Comment: You could symlink the folders you need. Or use https://laravel-tenancy.com/

Comment: @kerbholz I've never heard about it, I will give it a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could create a bash script that runs `composer update` for all of your projects.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/website.com && composer update package/name
cd /var/www/website2.com && composer update package/name
cd /var/www/website3.com && composer update package/name
```

Comment: I thinked about that, but I'm looking for some better way to do it, since the composer update for each project will do at least 20 diferent updates. And the package will be the same in major cases.
Anyway, thank you for the answer :)